# Azure Storage firewall open to Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

I have an Azure Storage account and need to enable the storage firewall.

I have added the **outbound** IP addresses of my App Service, but the firewall still prevents access. (I know that these addresses can change, but they change predictably, so I can live with that.)

Is there a solution to grant an App Service access to the Storage account other than disabling the firewall (and other than using an ASE, which isn't an option)?

Comment: May be this link helps:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/9f4d8aeb-68a6-4ec1-9e11-bee2d1301792/allow-access-to-azure-storage-account-only-from-an-app-service

Comment: @Joy Wang Thanks, but not really. Assuming you can live with the predictability of the App Services changing (in my case I can), an ASE/VPN is not required to achieve what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out that in a new Azure Storage account with a new App Service, setting the storage firewall to the outbound IPs of the App Service **does work as expected**. Unless the client browser is actually doing the download, adding the client's IP is **not** required.

**Edit**

This only works reliably when the storage account is **in a different data centre** to the App Service. When they are both in the same data centre, an internal outbound address (e.g. 10.x.x.x) is presented from the App Service to the Storage account. Internal addresses cannot be added to the Storage firewall.

Comment: How did you wind up solving this? Did you simply open the firewall to all networks? Setting up a virtual network seems like a lot of work to get these two services to communicate securely.

Comment: @Aaron There's no way around it. See Microsoft docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal#grant-access-from-an-internet-ip-range). `Network rules have no effect on requests originating from the same Azure region as the storage account. Use Virtual network rules to allow same-region requests.`

Answer (score 0):

If you access your web app service from on-premises networks, you need to grant access from your on-premise networks to your storage account with a public Internet-facing IP address used by your network. You can get more details from [Grant access from an internet IP range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security#grant-access-from-an-internet-ip-range)

If you have [VNet Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet) with your apps. You should first enable service endpoints for storage in the VNet. You can refer to [Grant access from a virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security#grant-access-from-a-virtual-network).

Comment: Thanks for your comments Nancy. The on-premise network does not need access directly to the Azure Storage unless the client browser is requesting the file directly from the Storage account. That's not what I wanted in my solution; rather the App Service reads the file from Storage and streams to the client. In that scenario, the App Service outbound IPs are what need to be added to the Storage firewall.